# How to move DataTable to another DataSet?

Tags: c#, datatable

How can I move the DataTable object from one dataset to another and avoid duplicating data in memory? Something, like this:

```
var ds1 = new DataSet();
var ds2 = new DataSet();
IDataAdapter da = myDataAdapterFactory.New();
da.Fill(ds1);
Console.WriteLine(ds1.Tables.Count);//1 
Console.WriteLine(ds2.Tables.Count);//0 
ds1.MoveDataTableTo(ds2, ds1.Tables[0]);
Console.WriteLine(ds1.Tables.Count);//0 
Console.WriteLine(ds2.Tables.Count);//1
```

---

I cannot spend memory, and it is the reason why I dont'use `DataTable.Copy()` or `DataSet.Merge()` or other ways to duplicate rows in memory.

Comment: what did you try? [documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablecollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) there is `Add`, `Remove`, and `CopyTo` among the methods of the `DataTableCollection`.

Comment: @jeroenh I don't need to  *copy* , I need to *move*

Comment: true, the accepted answer on the duplicate also does not address the "avoid duplicating data in memory" part of the question.

Comment: Did you try `dt = ds1.Tables[0]; ds1.Remove(dt); ds2.Add(dt);`?

Comment: @jeroenh, It worked. Can you post the answer, please? Presently, I see how it's simple, but I spent much time to find out solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the datatable you need to move, `Remove` it from the first dataset and `Add` it to the other

```
var dt = ds1.Tables[0]; 
ds1.Tables.Remove(dt); 
ds2.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
public DataTable CopyDataTable(DataTable dtSource)
{
        // cloned to get the structure of source
        DataTable dtDestination = dtSource.Clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < dtSource.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dtDestination.ImportRow(dtSource.Rows[i]);
        }
        return dtDestination;
}
```

Suppose you want to copy first table of sourceSet to destinationSet.
Call it like

```
DataTable destinationTable = CopyDataTable(ds1.Tables[0]);
DataSet destinationSet = new DataSet();
ds2.Tables.Add(destinationTable);
```

Comment: I want to avoid duplicating rows in the memory. `ImportRow()` will duplicate  them.